# c# - Call Interclass Asynch Task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-asynctask

I am kinda new to Xamarin.Android and still have a steep learning curve ;-). But i approached a problem which i don't find a solution even after a few days of googling and YouTube-ing.

Do somebody know how to call a async Task from another Class?

i want to call the public async Task ReadStringAsync() from the class MainActivity. How can i do that?

i want to call this:

```
class TextfileRead
{
    string[] StrData;

    String filename = "Arbeitszeiten.txt";
    String filepath = "myFileDir";
    String fileContent = "";

    public async Task<string> ReadStringAsync()
    {
        var backingFile = Path.Combine(filepath, filename);

        if (backingFile == null || !System.IO.File.Exists(backingFile))
        {
            return "oO, irgendwas ging schief";
        }

        string line;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(backingFile, true))
        {
            //string line;
            while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                //return line;
            }
        }
        return line;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a try with `TextfileRead textfileRead = new TextfileRead();string value = await textfileRead.ReadStringAsync();` to get the value from another class?

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks very much!
Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Glad it be helpful! I have updated the answer. You could mark it when you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **MainActiviy.cs**, you could use following ways to call `public async Task ReadStringAsync()`.

```
public async void getValue()
{
    TextfileRead textfileRead = new TextfileRead();
    string value = await textfileRead.ReadStringAsync();
}
```